# Angular get response size HTTP requests

Tags: angular, express, graphql, gzip, httpresponse

For my school project I want to know the compressed size of the result of a HTTP request. It is gzipped and there is no header where the size is given. This has to be done for two different types of API's, REST and GraphQL. For the graphql requests I use apollo. The size I need is [what is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKJ97.png).

The reason I want this is to compare the result size difference to check wether GraphQL is more efficient with it's data usage and how much more efficient it is.

If it is not possible to do this in Angular, the API is Node.js with express and I could add it there. The backend package for GraphQL I  use is express-graphql.

I couldn't find any possibilities, but I think that it should be possible. Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

You need `content-length` header.

Check this example, might be helpful:

```js
fetch('https://drag13.io/')
  .then((rawResponse)=> console.log(rawResponse.headers.get('content-length')))
```

Comment: In the backend I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression as gzipper, but this removes the content-length header. And when I add it myself, it's the size of the uncompressed content. :/

Comment: Hm, strange, let me check

Comment: Thanks! [this](https://scriptie.bastolen.nl/api/rest/nosql/articles) is the endpoint I use in the screenshot. It's publicly available, so if you want, here you can check the result I'm working with. It's 500 "articles" with dummy data used for checking the size difference

Comment: That's because it uses ```Transfer-Encoding: chunked``` 
Here is a gist where you can check how to process and calculate chanked data https://gist.github.com/jfsiii/034152ecfa908cf66178

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It comes very close, but this is the degzipped response. So the response I get from this gist is +-4MB, but the amount I want is +-57.9KB.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But I think I’m going to skip the automated process and just execute the request in Insomnia to get the size. I only need it to write my final paper, so this will have to do :(